# Windows GDI Context - CreateDIBSection

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

I am using `CreateDIBSection()` to create a HBITMAP from a buffer, but sometimes - with no regular occurrence - I get a NULL pointer from it. I can't understand what may cause the function to return a NULL pointer because - as I said before - it is not regular. Sometimes it happens after displaying 10 frames, sometimes after 2 frames.
Can someone explain me which are the possible reasons of the unexpected fail?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return when it fails?

Comment: @Alan GetLastError is not set for `CreateDIBSection`. At least not according to the docs.

Comment: @David The documentation is somewhat unclear - it says the function returns NULL for failure, and also that it can "return" ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Comment: @Alan If SetLastError was called it would say so. You have to check for NULL or ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. Those are the failure modes.

Comment: The online MSDN Library page is broken, unlike my local copies.  It definitely sets the GetLastError return value.

Comment: No, it returns 0. Called just after it.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have an evidence of your claim?

Comment: I can confirm that ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER is not a return value but rather a GetLastError value. To verify, pass an invalid value to the `usage` parameter such as 12345. The return value is 0 and GetLastError is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Comment: Submitted https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/pull/679 to fix the bad docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this function is failing at random, I would be inclined to think that the buffer is not correctly formatted or is messed up. Go back in the code that creates the buffer and see if any of the functions fail there. I would suspect that a functions return status is not being correctly checked before the code continues.